# How do I sync this code to wait for the AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, synchronized

I'm doing an app with Android Studio. I have so far created the registration and login phases.

In the registration, the most important checks are that user, mail and phone number must be unique (compared to minor checks, such as regex), in the login phase check that the user exists and then check that the password is the same as I have in the database and above all that the user is not locked (number ranging from 0 to 3 to report errors made in entering the pass).

What's going on? That when I enter the data, both for login and for registration, and I press the button to start the checks that validate the access/registration (execute all checks), all checks to be carried out, but the whole function crashes. Let me give you an example:

first press:
check username (without result),

second press:
check username (with result) and check phone (without result)

third press:
check username (with result) and check phone (with result) and check mail (without result)

fourth press:
check username (with result) and check phone (with result) and check mail (with result), that's ok!

Then the functions are performed together, replying to the user of the product result (ex: wrong telephone number).

This only happens if there are AsyncTask. I say that for each of them I set a 7-second timer for the connection, but every "first time" does not last half a second (the ProgressDialog appears and disappears and no Toast programmed appears, while in the following executions the ProgressDialog lasts the time established and responds correctly to the result of the operation).

**Activity - Click  Button**

```
public synchronized void provapost(View v) {

    boolean ci = controllointernet(), cs = false, cn = false, cm = false, ct = false, cp = false, cname = false, cc = false, cl = false, cd = false;

    if (ci) {
        cn = controllonickname();
    } else...

    if (ci && cn) {
        cp = controllopassword(); //works correctly, no asynctask, all Java instructions
    } else...

    if (ci && cn && cp) {
        ct = controllotelefono();
    } else...

   if (ci && cn && cp && ct) {
        cm = controllomail();
    } else...
```

**controllonickname Method (similarly to controllotelefono and controllomail)**

```
String u = user.getText().toString();
ControlloUsername task = new ControlloUsername(this);
task.execute(u);
task.setOnFinishListener(new ControlloUsername.onFinishListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFinish(String res) {
           // The task has finished and you can now use the result
           if (res.contains("xxx")) {...
              ...
              ...
       ...}
        });
```

**ControlloUsername (always similarly to other Asynctasks)**

```
public class ControlloUsername extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Context context;
ProgressDialog a;
onFinishListener mListener; // Create a variable for your interface

// Define the interface & callbacks
public interface onFinishListener{
    // Replace 'variableType' with the appropriate type for your result
    void onFinish(String myResult);
}

public void setOnFinishListener(onFinishListener l){
    mListener = l;
}

public ControlloUsername(Context ct) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context = ct;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    a=new ProgressDialog(context);
    a.setTitle("Send");
    a.setMessage("Sending..Please wait");
    a.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) { //sync
    if(mListener != null){
        mListener.onFinish(result);
    }
    a.dismiss();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    a.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) { //sync
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String username = params[0];
    String login_url = Connector.db + "script/usercontrol.php";
    String resultado = "";

    URL u = null;
    try {
        u = new URL(login_url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection http = null;
    try {
        http = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
        resultado = writer.toString();
    }
        http.setDoInput(true);
        http.setDoOutput(true);



    try {
        http.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        OutputStream out = http.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
        bf.write(post_data);
        bf.flush();
        bf.close();
        out.close();
        InputStream in = http.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "iso-8859-1"));
        String result = "";
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        bf.close();
        in.close();
        http.disconnect();
        return result;
    } catch (ConnectException e) {
        ...
}
...
}
```

VIDEO: https://youtu.be/BLIp7YmiphM

In the example of the video, I initially verify that the user exists, then I check the password, and in case it is wrong, I decrease the number of possible errors, until I block the account to the "fourth error" (which is the seventh). The FIRST THREE TIMES I press, I start the userControl/passControl/refreshErrors-AsyncTasks (about the next few times, I think I have problems with synchronizing between methods that take and put data on the db).

I had problems before because the AsyncTasks blocked the user interface, so I used this alternative method. Could it be the non-use and non-implementation of the OnPostExecute?

I did the debugging to see if there was any steps that were skipped, but actually everything is done correctly and it also seems to return the result to UiThread, which does not work and does not show toast. Whenever the AsyncTask "doesn't work," the corresponding ProgressDialog lasts very little time, only then it seems to last for as long as it takes.
I can't even wait for the response, because They suggested I use a FinishListener to prevent the UiThread from crashing. I do not know if at this point I have to use a Semaphore to wait and proceed to completed check, but I do not know where it should be inserted and how to apply it.
I have the impression that it is as if the "first time" fails to connect to the server: in fact I have set a timer to the connection of 7 seconds, but, as I said, every "first time" the AsyncTask lasts very little, appears and disappears in less than a second. Only later does it work properly.

What can it be? Thank you very much :)

***NEW INFO:***
I noticed that the function corresponding to the button for registration, in the Registration Activity, continues its execution without waiting for the response of the checkusername function (see Activity class).
Then it proceeds for the first time considering that the global variable (which changes to true if the username is available) is false and the second time considering that the variable is true (obviously it was true the previous time).
How can I synchronize and wait for the answer and the real value?

***2019-09-28 06:05:10.269 8309-8309/oneforyou.jep.oneforyou D/TEST: variable false***

***2019-09-28 06:05:10.317 8309-8431/oneforyou.jep.oneforyou D/TEST: Nickname available!***

***2019-09-28 06:05:13.783 8309-8309/oneforyou.jep.oneforyou D/TEST: variable true***

***2019-09-28 06:05:13.836 8309-8430/oneforyou.jep.oneforyou D/TEST: Nickname NOT available!***

Here the result is ok, but the username has been changed to an unavailable one... As you can see, the true value of the global variable is inherited from the previous execution, not from the current one. I think it's a synchronization problem or type of variable problem (volatile, static, final...).
**controllonickname produces the value, next instructions consume this information.**
I don't understand why he does this, I am sincere.

Comment: What does logcat say? Have you debugged it at all?

Comment: I did the debugging to see if there was any steps that were skipped, but actually everything is done correctly and it also seems to return the result to UiThread, which does not work and does not show toast. Whenever the AsyncTask "doesn't work," the corresponding ProgressDialog lasts very little time, only then it seems to last for as long as it takes

Comment: I can't even wait for the response, because They suggested I use a FinishListener to prevent the UiThread from crashing. I do not know if at this point I have to use a Semaphore to wait and proceed to completed check, but I do not know where it should be inserted and how to apply it

Comment: I have the impression that it is as if the "first time" fails to connect to the server: in fact I have set a timer to the connection of 7 seconds, but, as I said, every "first time" the AsyncTask lasts very little, appears and disappears in less than a second. Only later does it work properly

Comment: That's why the first thing I said is "what does logcat say?". This code you attached doesn't show any exception handling. Looks like user would have no idea if anything wrong happened. Just like you are right now. Set a breakpoint in task itself and in the catch blocks, watch logcat.

Comment: :) thank you, test it.

Comment: ***2019-09-27 17:52:04.665 32190-32419/oneforyou.jep.oneforyou D/TEST: Nickname: available

***2019-09-27 17:52:04.678 32190-32235/oneforyou.jep.oneforyou W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x74b4caf010 disconnect failed

***2019-09-27 17:52:04.693 643-643/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing Surface(name=2e65b28 Wait...)/@0x4598f7d - animation-leash to Surface(name=2e65b28 Wait...)/@0x4598f7d - animation-leash#1

***2019-09-27 17:52:04.699 1279-1344/? I/StatusBarDisable: setFlags what=0 which=1 pkg=Window{b194726 u0 oneforyou.jep.oneforyou/oneforyou.jep.oneforyou.Registrazione}

Comment: Package : com.google.android.inputmethod.latin,uid : 10370 does not have permission to access THP interfaces

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I noticed that the function corresponding to the button for registration, in the Registration Activity, continues its execution without waiting for the response of the checkusername function.
Then it proceeds for the first time considering that the global variable (which changes to true if the username is available) is false and the second time considering that the variable is true (obviously it was true the previous time).
How can I synchronize and wait for the answer and the real value?

Comment: You may want to call `task.setOnFinishListener` before `task.execute(u)`

Comment: Aaaaah, maybe may be, I hope so :) I try it tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: @GiddyNaya unfortunately no :( i have to synchronize controllonickname function, that change the value of a static value (resultnick)...

Comment: controllonickname produces the value, next instructions consume this information